# 301 Redirects using Typepad

Tags: redirect, typepad

Does any know if it is possible to do redirects using Typepad?

Not domain mapping but pure honest to goodness 301 redirects.  There seems to be some mention of a .htaccess file put in the root of the site working but it has not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your header, you can add a meta Refresh tag with time set to zero, pointing to your new blog.

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
```

If Typepad allows, insert this inside your `<head>` section.  And while you're at it, add a rel=canonical tag pointing to your new domain, too.